# Room Database: Still getting "no value passed for parameter 'id' " even though it is meant to be autogenerated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here's my Room Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "matched_users")
data class MatchedUser(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "match_id") val matchId: String
)
```

and here is me instantiating it in my Fragment:

```
private fun pass(){
    CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
            val match = MatchedUser()
       CustomApplication.database?.matchedUsersDao()?.addMatchUid(match)
            Log.d(TAG, "Added matchId to DB")
        }
    return removeUser2()
}
```

When I hover over `MatchedUser()` it still says I need to pass a parameter for `id` .. but it is meant to be autogenerated as stated in the Entity.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

In `kotlin` data class each variable should be initialized, so you may set default arguments in your data class constructor, like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "matched_users")
data class MatchedUser(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "match_id") val matchId: String
){
    constructor(matchId: String): this(Int.MIN_VALUE, matchId)
}
```

Now you can insert data by providing only `match_id` to the `constructor` of the data class, like this:

```
private fun pass(){
    CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
            val match = MatchedUser("1")
       CustomApplication.database?.matchedUsersDao()?.addMatchUid(match)
            Log.d(TAG, "Added matchId to DB")
        }
    return removeUser2()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the constructor and getter method in the class MatchedUser.
Then create an instance with parametr id = 0:

```
val match = MatchedUser(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin class, you must assign default values to the primary constructor either through secondary constructor or directly creating its object.

Secondary constructor inside the MatchedUser class having default values of declared types:

> ```
> constructor():this(0, "")
> ```
>
> `val match = MatchedUser()`

OR

Having no additional constructor and simply initializing class object using primary constructor:

> `val match = MatchedUser(0,"")`